# Error in cypress end-to-end YML script of GitHub Actions

Tags: github, cypress, github-actions

I want to run cypress end-to-end tests whenever I push a commit to my GitHub repository.

I get errors during running GitHub Action

> Run cypress-io/github-action@v2
>
> /usr/bin/docker exec
> fa4cf350fc5f858e8192af07e8ec8cc98615724927611862a1b8333b355c2388 sh -c
> "cat /etc/*release | grep ^ID"
>
> /usr/local/bin/npm ci
>
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! syscall spawn git
>
> npm ERR! path git
>
> npm ERR! errno -2
>
> npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
>
> npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t
> ssh://git@github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-cise.git
>
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>
> npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!
> /github/home/.npm/_logs/2022-06-03T06_35_32_523Z-debug.log
>
> Error: The process '/usr/local/bin/npm' failed with exit code 254

Below is the YML script

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  cypress-e2e:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images
    container: cypress/browsers:node14.17.6-chrome100-ff98
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: Headless Chrome
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        timeout-minutes: 10
        with:
          build: npm run build
          start: node server.js
          browser: chrome
          headless: true
```

below are my package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/core": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/router": "^13.3.11",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^12.1.2",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "a-color-picker": "^1.2.1",
    "angular2-draggable": "^2.3.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cytoscape": "^3.21.1",
    "cytoscape-cise": "github:iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-cise#develop",
    "cytoscape-context-menus": "github:iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-context-menus#unstable",
    "cytoscape-expand-collapse": "github:iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-expand-collapse#unstable",
    "cytoscape-fcose": "github:iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-fcose#unstable",
    "cytoscape-layout-utilities": "github:iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-layout-utilities#unstable",
    "cytoscape-navigator": "^2.0.1",
    "cytoscape-panzoom": "^2.5.3",
    "cytoscape-view-utilities": "github:iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-view-utilities#unstable",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.13",
    "http": "0.0.1-security",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "ngx-autosize-input": "^13.1.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^13.3.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.38",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "css": "^3.0.0",
    "cypress": "^9.7.0",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^5.9.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.20",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5"
  }
```

Comment: Please show your package.json

Comment: Note that the checkout action is available in v3

Comment: @rethab added my dependencies.

Comment: The "scripts" would be more important ;-)

Comment: how is that? It is not using any scripts at all